# Send messages with whatsapi.net?

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I want to send messages using whatsapi and this was my try

```
string nickname = "Test";
string sender = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";         
//My Phone Number tryed with 049xxxxxxxxxxxx, 0049xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, 49xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
string imei = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//My IMEI 
WhatsApp me = new WhatsApp(sender,imei ,nickname,true);
me.Connect();
Console.WriteLine(me.ConnectionStatus);// I get a Connection!
Console.ReadLine();
me.SendMessage("xxxxxxxxxx", "This is a Test!");// Send Message
//No Message received :(
me.Disconnect();
Console.WriteLine(me.ConnectionStatus);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Now where is my mistake? and how I'm doing it right?

I'm using this version: https:[//github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet](https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet).

First I just want to send messages.
When I try to get a request from the WART, I just get this message:

```
Could not request code using either sms or voice.
SMS: {"status":"fail","reason":"no routes","retry_after": 3600}
Voice: {"status":"fail","reason":"no routes","retry_after": 3600}
```

Comment: please describe more about solution . i install whatsapp in visual studio then use your code and connect disconnect but not send and i dont have any message from result of that sent like incorrect imie or number ... nothing... please help me and help this good page that you created

Comment: https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet. does not seem to exist anymore

Answer (score 5):

```
    WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("your number", "your password", "pankaj", false, false);
    wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
    {
        Response.Write("connect");
        wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
        {
            wa.SendMessage("to", "msg");
        };

        wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
        {
            Response.Write("login failed"+data);
        };
        wa.Login();
    };
    wa.OnConnectFailed+= (ex)=>
    {
        Response.Write("connection failed");
    }
```

Comment: Pankaj, can you please tell me the number for which we request the code, must have whats app user.

Comment: give your phone number.

Comment: im getting auth response error , ive heard whatsapp has put a ban on this feature

Comment: @PankajGupta is it still possible to use WhatsApp Api as i have seen some ban on it and  WhatsAppApi.Register.WhatsRegisterV2.RequestCode not working.

Comment: how to get password?

Answer (score 3):

download installer for generate password https://github.com/mgp25/WART from this link

after that pass your mobile no and password which you got. and pass user detail like his no or msg in constructor in whatsapp object.

it will work for you.
try with it.

Answer (score -8):

After the connect put the command to Login. I resolved this way:

```
me.connect(); 
me.login(null);
```

Comment: Any additional information on how to do this or why this works would greatly help your answer.

Comment: I don't know why this work, just try to use this code:
me.connect();
me.login(null);