# WhatsApp c# WhatsAPINet - Login failed: not-authorized

Tags: c#, .net, whatsapp

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745722/c-sharp-how-to-send-messages-with-whatsapi-net/30491624#30491624) and [Andre Soares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324445/andre-soares) I have managed to write correct code for connecting to WhatsApp and sending simple message.

```
using System;
using WhatsAppApi;
using WhatsAppApi.Register;

namespace WhatsAppBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("********", "********", "sakher", false, false);
            // I tried with phone numbers like "38xxxxxxx", "+38xxxxxxx". 
            // The phone number wasn't previously registered in WhatsApp.
            // Password was generated using WART. 
            wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection success!");
                    wa.SendMessage("********", "Hello World!");
                    // Number is correct and registered in WhatsApp
                    Console.WriteLine("Message sent!");
                };

                wa.OnLoginFailed += data => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Login failed: {0}", data);
                    // Login failed: not-authorized 
                };
                wa.Login();
            };
            wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connect failed: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            };
            wa.Connect();
            wa.Disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine("BYE");
        }
    }
}
```

I have generated password in WART for several times for the same number, but none worked.

An App simply says: Login failed: not-authorized.

Perhaps, someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I'm also getting the same problem.

Comment: It's almost definitely because whatsapp changed their authentication and broke WART because not only do they *not* support a public API, they explicitly try to stop people from using their service without their app.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Send To details
     string Phnumber = textBox1.Text;
     string message = textBox2.Text;

     //send From details

     string FromNumber = "917673943979";
     string password = "aaRvxtEbePyI/uBOqpqw9yeHlys=";
     string nickName = "Dayakar";

     WhatsApp wap = new WhatsApp(FromNumber, password, nickName, false, false);
     wap.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp SuccessFully...");

             wap.OnLoginSuccess += (PhoneNumber, data) =>
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("Enterned");
                 wap.SendMessage(Phnumber, message);
                 MessageBox.Show("Message Sent Successfully...");
             };

             wap.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(data);
                 MessageBox.Show("Yes Failed login : {0}", data);
             };

             wap.Login();
         };

     wap.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Conncetion Failure");
         };

     wap.Connect();
 }
```

Comment: It is working but after few times of run and restart the program I get Login Failed : not-authorized ! So how to solve this issue ? is there is a time to reconnect ?

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBxpfm3kmmgNGtKNkRTRF9fS0k/view?pli=1
 use this dll this worked for me , try to use a new whats app no , freshly registered from wart

code used was

```
      WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(sender, password, nickname, true, true);
      wa.OnConnectSuccess += () => {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection success!");
            wa.SendMessage(target, "testing C# Api,sent via C#");
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent!");
        };
        wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failed: {0}", data);
        };
        wa.Login();
      };
      wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Connect failed: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
      };
      wa.Connect();
      Console.WriteLine("END");
```