# whatsapp c# Auth response error

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I'm using the last nuget version for whatsapp:
 [WhastApp API 1.2.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Whatsapp.NET/) and reading tutorials about configure my whatsapp in my application.
I'm using my localhost to test and my code is:

```
string from = "503XXXX";
            string to = "503XXXX";
            string msg = "lorem ipsum";

            WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(from, "jd8eY3FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "MrMins", true);

            wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
                                       {
                                           wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        wa.SendMessage(to, msg);
                                                                    };
                                       };

            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {
                //Fail message
            };

            wa.Login();

            wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
            {
                //ConnectionFailed
            };

            wa.Connect();
            wa.SendMessage(to, msg);
            wa.Disconnect();
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Auth response error
```

I updated my whatsapp password with [WART](https://github.com/mgp25/WART) and logged me out from my whatsapp mobile (I think is the correct behavior), but is still not working.

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: I had similar question see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745722/c-sharp-how-to-send-messages-with-whatsapi-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine, your code area is: 503 and your phone number is 555555555555

```
WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("503555555555555", "get the password using WART", "your nickname", false, false);
            wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
            {
                Response.Write("connect");
                wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
                {
                    wa.SendMessage("Destinatino number (50377777777777)", "Youre custom message");
                };

                wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
                {
                    Response.Write("login failed"+data);
                };
                wa.Login();
            };
            wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
                                      {
                                          Response.Write("connection failed");
                                      }
                ;

            wa.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is, that you try to send a message also if the connection failed. Try this instead of your code to send a message:

```
WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("your number", "your password", "your nickname", false, false);
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
    Response.Write("connect");
    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno,data) =>
    {
        wa.SendMessage("to", "msg");
    };

    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
    {
        Response.Write("login failed"+data);
    };
    wa.Login();
};
wa.OnConnectFailed+= (ex)=>
{
    Response.Write("connection failed");
}
```

This avoids the sending if the connection failed.

PS: If in your code the connection succeeded you would send the message twice.