# whatsapp c# Auth response error using WhatsAppApi

Tags: c#, whatsapp, whatsapi

i need to connect with whats app message but

---

i find difficulty  with an error can't determine it

---

```
string from = "+965********"; //( )
        string to = txt_To.Text; // Mobile Number(+2011104******)
        string msg = txt_Message.Text;
        WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp wa = new WhatsAppApi.WhatsApp(from, "1RTy***************=", "yahia", false, false);
            wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Connected to WhatsApp...");
                    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phonenumber, data) =>
                    {
                        wa.SendMessage(to, msg);
                        MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
                    };
                    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed : {0} : ", data);
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        wa.Login();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                };


            wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed...");
            };
            wa.Connect();
        }
```

i try Mobil number with country code and without it. but no respone

Comment: What exception message is being returned?

Comment: Message ==>auth response error

Comment: And is the exception being raised at this point in your code..?

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

Comment: yes in
catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }

Comment: WhatsApp have made changes to prevent people automating requests using there API it's against their policy and they can ban your WhatsApp Account  I found this on the GitHut Repository https://github.com/rafaellincoln/WhatsAPINet/issues/4

Comment: Your issue looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071540/whatsapp-c-sharp-auth-response-error - perhaps the solution to that will resolve your fault also?

Comment: @Nick Allan my solution exactly equal to the solution in the last link that you post but also the message appeaar

Comment: I think Joshua Duxbury's suggestion is very likely the cause of your issue.