# Issues Configuring WhatsApp API (C#)

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, whatsapi

I'm trying to configure WhatsApp API in C#. I tried to implement it using examples such as:

- http://www.dotnetprogramer.in/2016/01/how-to-send-whatsapp-message-through-csharp-net-application-by-using-csharp-coding.html
- [Send messages with whatsapi.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745722/send-messages-with-whatsapi-net)

Looking into the aforementioned examples, i came to know that i'll require a WhatsApp password in order to send a message.

I downloaded a tool named WART (WhatsApp Registration Tool) from this site

- https://github.com/mgp25/WART

and tried to get my whatsApp password by adding a phone number in following format.

- (xx - xxxxxxxxxx) CountryCode - 10 Digit Phone number

Consider the following image:

[image]

But when i ask and request for the Code, this is what it says.

[image]

I looked for alternatives and found this useful point

- In case WART isn't working, use this online tool: http://watools.es/pwd.html

but unfortunately this site seems to be unavailable.

I ALSO looked into more alternatives and found this WhatsApp API

- https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master/examples

but this seems to be in Php, i don't really have the expertise to make the registerTool.php work.

Am i missing something here? Is the whatsApp API deprecated? Any sort of help/direction would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged as PHP when you want it for C#?

Comment: @Naruto I've discussed my issue which has a possible solution in PHP as well. I'm open to solutions, if the registerTool.php is somehow made to work, i'll give me my whatsApp password.

Comment: This question should be flagged as too broad or asking for a tool or reference. You are asking for help over several tools with no debugging information. You also generally ask if there are other tools available.